# Slow shutdown using AsyncWriteEngine in MapDb

Tags: java, mapdb

I am using MapDB on Windows 7 with Java 8. 
My map is quite big - approximately 10.8 Gb in the .p data file. I am using the AsyncWriteEngine and it takes a long time to close. I observer it writes out very infrequently when there is no disk, memory or CPU bound. Is there a way to speed this up?

Here is how I create my MapDb instance. Let me know if there are other details that might be useful in speeding this up.

```
        db = DBMaker
                .newFileDB(dbFile)
                .transactionDisable()
                .mmapFileEnable()
                .asyncWriteEnable()
                .make();
```

Answer (score 0):

MapDB has datapump which can create BTreeMap very fast. An example is here
https://github.com/jankotek/MapDB/blob/release-1.0/src/test/java/examples/Huge_Insert.java